# How to check whether a generic type has a property by name in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have below code in typescript. In the body of the function, I'd like to check whether each `key` in the `event` exists in the type `T`. How can I do that in `typescript`?

```
export const convert = <T>(event: { [key: string]: any }) => {
   // how can I check whether each key in event exists in type T
}
```

In this function, I'd like to save the `event` to Postgresql table so I'd like to filter out fields which don't exist in table columns.

If `T` is removed after compilation, can I use a `class` to do that?

Like in below class, it maps to database table columns. Can I filter out the fields in the `event` based on the fields declared in this class?

```
class Entity {
   @column()
   id!: string;
   @column
   name? : string;
```

Comment: You can't because types are erased at compile time (no info about `T` exist at runtime)

Comment: What exactly do you want? What do you want to have as a result of this check? Type or to be able wrapping code in this condition?

Comment: Even in case of class keys won't be part of prototype and you won't be able to query them

Answer (score 0):

consider the following, but `event` must be typed as well

```
export const convert = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(event: Record<keyof T, unknown>) => {
```

Comment: the `event` is passed from API gateway which is over http. So I don't have a way to constrain the type for that. If the event has fields more than `T` has, it will include these un-needed fields right?

Comment: in that case typescript can't help you. during run-time there's no typescript, it's compiled to pure js. so you have to implement run-time logic.